# JUnit Tests error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/platform/commons/PreconditionViolationException

Tags: java, testing, gradle, junit, visual-studio-code

First of all I'm using VSCODE (using the Java Test Runner extension) to write this program in Java and when trying to run tests I receive this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/platform/commons/PreconditionViolationException
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestLoader.createFilteredTest(JUnit5TestLoader.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestLoader.createTest(JUnit5TestLoader.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit5TestLoader.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:526)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.platform.commons.PreconditionViolationException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 7 more
```

I'm using Gradle and here are my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.hyperledger.fabric-chaincode-java:fabric-chaincode-shim:1.4.3'
    implementation 'com.owlike:genson:1.5'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.10.1'

    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.4.2'
    testImplementation 'org.assertj:assertj-core:3.11.1'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.+'
}
```

Comment: Did you try with `testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api")` and `testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine")`? Also you need a `test` task: `test { useJUnitPlatform() }`

Comment: @x80486 `org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter` is an aggregator dependency that bundles everything needed (see e.g. [Gradle example project](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples/blob/r5.6.2/junit5-jupiter-starter-gradle/build.gradle#L12)).

Comment: So, does it runs successfully configured in such way in the CLI? I always go with the Gradle documentation, that's why I had it in such way. I guess both are valid, but in your case it brings up more dependencies.

Comment: @x80486 I already try that, still not working

Answer (score 2):

this page maybe can provide you some informations:

https://github.com/iluwatar/java-design-patterns/issues/1007

as it talked about, maybe you need 'junit-platform-commons'.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

- List Upgrade the `org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter` to `5.6.0`

Or

- Adding testImplementation('org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher:1.5.2')

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error with Visual Studio Code 1.53.2 in a Gradle 6.8.2 project when I switched to JUnit 5 from JUnit 4. To switch to JUnit 5, I made the following changes to my build script `build.gradle` as instructed in this Gradle [user guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#using_junit5):

```
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.6.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine'
}
```

While the above allowed me to run `.\gradlew.bat test` successfully, Visual Studio Code wouldn't allow me to run the tests from within the editor itself and would abort with the error shared in the post.

To solve this, I followed the instructions [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-debug/issues/692#issuecomment-544364859) i.e. in VS Code, press F1 and type/select 'Java: Clean Java Language Server Workspace'. This solved the above error and JUnit 5 tests now run from within the editor again.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this issue as well, and found the solution was to upgrade the version of JUnit Jupiter API.

- Windows: `10.0.19044`
- VSCode: `1.67.1`
- Test Runner for Java plugin: `v0.35.0`

The version of JUnit Jupiter API that didn't work and gave me the following error was `5.3.1`:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/platform/commons/PreconditionViolationException
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestLoader.createFilteredTest(JUnit5TestLoader.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestLoader.createTest(JUnit5TestLoader.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit5TestLoader.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:513)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:756)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.platform.commons.PreconditionViolationException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
URLClassLoader.java:381
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
ClassLoader.java:424
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
Launcher.java:349
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
ClassLoader.java:357
    ... 7 more
```

The version of JUnit Jupiter API that works is `5.8.2`.